# how to send data in GET request header using react and axios to Django rest framework?

Tags: django, reactjs, react-redux, axios

i am new to react and axios and i want to know how to send data in my headers using get request
i tried this but it didn't work

** i observed that the request type changed to options in django terminal window **

```
export const getUserOrders=(userID)=>{
    return dispatch=>{
        dispatch(getUserOrdersStart())
        axios.defaults.headers={
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            id:userID
        }
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admindashboard/userorders/')
        .then(res=>{
            const order=res.data
            dispatch(getUserOrdersSuccess(order))
        }).catch(err=>{
            getUserOrdersFail(err)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever your client app is on different domain than that of server, client will send an `OPTION` call, no worries

Comment: i am creating admin panel and i need to get user's every order he had done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the approach below a whirl.

```
export const getUserOrders = async userId => {
      const header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",    
      };
      let id = userId;
      const URL = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admindashboard/userorders/`
      return dispatch => {
        try {
          dispatch(getUserOrdersStart())

           const response = await axios(URL,id, {
            method: "GET",
            mode: "cors",
            headers: header,

          });
          const jsonResponse = response.json();
          dispatch(getUserOrdersSuccess(order))
        } catch (error) {
          setError(error);
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding CORS headers

Use this package and read the docs

https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers